# Auth Token is not working properly in Alamofire, Swift

Tags: swift, authorization, alamofire

I want to validate the OTP of created user. I'm using POST RESTful API for this. All created user have their Auth token. So when i'm validating the user OTP, it says 'Invalid Authentication', but i'm sending the Token in the POST Request Header?
Here is my code :-

```
let urlString = "http://192.168.182.81:8080/serviceplus/user/validateotp.json"
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

            let headers = [
                "Authorization": "\(token)",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            ]              

            Alamofire.request(.POST, URLRequest, headers: headers, parameters: ["otpcode": fields[0].text!]).responseJSON { response in
                print("Error :- \(response.result.error)")
                print("Result values :- \(response.result.value)")
            }
        }
```

What should i do?

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"Bearer \(token)"` (or something similar)? Please check if the generated header looks like you want it to.

Comment: I'm using this one  "Authorization": "\(token)". @Thilo

Comment: And that is supposed to work? Don't you need to specify the Auth type? Or is that already part of `token`?

Comment: Still not working for me.@Thilo